# Cryptic C++ "thing" (function pointer)

Tags: c++, function, pointers

What is this syntax for in C++? Can someone point me to the technical term so I can see if I find anything in my text?

At first I thought it was a prototype but then the `=` and `(*fn)` threw me off...

Here is my example:

```
void (*fn) (int&,int&) = x;
```

Comment: Google for the "right-left rule". You may also be interested in the cdecl tool.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I haven't played with function pointers but now I understand function pointers better.

Comment: You can always use http://cdecl.org/ to get some help reading things out.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It can be rewritten to

```
typedef void (*T) (int&, int&);
T fn = x;
```

The 2nd statement is obvious, which should have solved that `= x;` question. In the 1st statement, we make `T` as a synonym as the type `void(*)(int&, int&)`, which means:

- a pointer to a function (`(*…)`)
- returning `void`
- and taking 2 arguments: `int&, int&`.

Answer (score 9):

That is a function pointer to a function taking two `int` reference parameters, which returns nothing. The function pointer is called `fn` and is being assigned the value in `x`.

Answer (score 2):

This declares and initializes a function pointer.

The name of the variable is `fn`, and it points to a function with the following signature:

```
void pointedToFunction(int&, int&)
```

The variable `fn` is initialized to the value contained in `x`.

The pointed-to function can be called using the following syntax:

```
int a;
int b;
(*fn)(a,b);
```

This is equivalent to

```
int a;
int b;
pointedToFunction(a,b);
```

Answer (score 2):

Function pointer.

http://www.newty.de/fpt/intro.html#what

^ Okay source for a beginner. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is a pointer to a function that takes two references to `int`s and returns `void`.

Answer (score 0):

That seems like a function pointer to a method that takes two integer references and does not return anything. The pointer will be named fn. You are assigning it to the address of x, which is hopefully a function that matches this description.

Answer (score 0):

It's a function pointer to a function that takes 2 integers as arguments and returns void. x must be a function name.

Comment: Actually, they are references to integers, not integers (No, I am not the downvoter)

Answer (score 0):

It's a function pointer variable that gets initialized to the stuff to the right of `=`.

The function type could be written like this:

```
typedef void func_t(int&,int&);
```

The function pointer than would be:

```
typedef func_t *fn_t;
```

With these definitions the variable declaration would be much clearer:

```
 fn_t fn = ...;
```

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia page with a few links on the subject: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer